# Randomly fill in an multidimentional array with elements from a List

Tags: java

I have an array of Cells. `public static Cell[][] island = new Cell[3][3];`
Each Cell has x and y cooddinates and list of animals that "dwell" inside of a cell. I need to randomly fill in this array with random animals from the list. `public static List<Alive> allanimals = new ArrayList<>();`
That's how I coded the list and "filling".

```
public static void generateIsland() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        if (random < 50) {
            allanimals.add(new Bear(500,5,0,0));
        } else {
            allanimals.add(new Sheep(70,0,0));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Randomly create all animals list" + allanimals);
    int initialcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            try {
                int randomdata = r.nextInt(0, allanimals.size() );

                List<Alive> animalsInCell = new ArrayList<>();

                animalsInCell = allanimals.subList(initialcount, initialcount + randomdata);

                initialcount += randomdata;

                island[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, animalsInCell);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                island[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, new ArrayList<Alive>());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end I have a lit of empty cells and I believe this part `animalsInCell = allanimals.subList(initialcount, initialcount + randomdata);` can be done more elegantly. How do I fill in my Island array with elements from the allanimals list?
This is my Cell class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Cell extends Thread{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public List<Alive> animals;
//method run()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would populate the initial list like this using a ternary (?:) operator.  You can still do the 50% version like yours but the `true` or `false` is, imo, more descriptive.

```
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      allanimals.add(r.nextBoolean() ? new Bear(500,5,0,0) 
                                     : new Sheep(70,0,0));
```

Since they are already randomly generated, just iterate over the list and add them to the cell in order. Or if you really want to randomize them again, you can shuffle the list and then add them.

```
Collections.shuffle(allanimals);
```

Regarding the other problem of empty cells. Consider this:

- Only save the list in the Cell if the current tally allows it, otherwise assign an empty list.
- if it does allow it, then update the initial count.
- Remember that if this count isn't used the next generated count might be.

```
Random r = new Random();
int initialCount = 0;
Cell[][] island = new Cell[3][3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            int randomData = r.nextInt(initialCount,allanimals.size());
            if (initialCount + randomData < allanimals.size()) {
                  animalsInCell = new ArrayList<>(
                    allanimals.subList(initialCount,
                            initialCount + randomData));
                    initialCount += randomData;

            } else {
                animalsInCell = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            island[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, animalsInCell);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how all this works together. Run it several times to observe the output.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class FillCell {
    static class Alive{
    }
    static class Bear extends Alive {
        int a, b,  c,  d;

        public Bear(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
            this.d = d;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bear [a=" + a + ", b=" + b + ", c=" + c + ", d="
                    + d + "]";
        }
        
    }
    static class Sheep extends Alive {
        int a, b,  c;
        
        public Sheep(int a, int b, int c) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Sheep [a=" + a + ", b=" + b + ", c=" + c+"]";
        }
        
    }
    
    List<Alive> allanimals = new ArrayList<>();
    
    record Cell(int i, int j, List<Alive> list) {
        public String toString() {
            String r = "Cell:" + i + " " + j+"\n";
            for (Alive a : list) {
                r += "     " + a+"\n";
            }
            return r;
        }
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FillCell().start();
    }
    
    public void start() {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
              allanimals.add(r.nextBoolean() ? new Bear(500,5,0,0) 
                                             : new Sheep(70,0,0));
        }
        int initialCount = 0;
        
        List<Alive> animalsInCell;
        Cell[][] island = new Cell[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if (initialCount < allanimals.size()) {
                        int randomData = r.nextInt(allanimals.size()-initialCount);
                          animalsInCell = new ArrayList<>(
                            allanimals.subList(initialCount,
                                    initialCount + randomData));
                          initialCount += randomData;

                    } else {
                        animalsInCell = new ArrayList<>();
                    }
                    island[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, animalsInCell);
                }
            }
        
     
        for (Cell[] cells : island ) {
            for (Cell cell : cells) {
                System.out.println(cell);
            }
        }
        }
    
}

If you want a greater population, just increase the initial size of the animal list.
```